# Install files to sdcard on Android/IOS with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I have some files that I need to copy to a folder once the user has installed my app. I was trying to find a way to transfer the files directly from the application root directory but no luck. I had also seen a suggestion about zipping the files and including the zipped file in my package, then extracting them to the folder. But did not know how to implement either methods.

Another alternative is to download and install the files when the app starts, but didnt want to rely on having to maintain the files on a server or that the user always has internet access since my app can be run offline.

How do I do this with a Phonegap/JQM/Javascript app?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: _I was trying to find a way to transfer the files directly from the application root directory but no luck._. Care to explain a little more? So you tried to move the files on first start-up and it didn't succeed?

Comment: tried using phonegap file transfer but could not access the root directory of the app to copy the file.

Comment: Yes, you can read (but not write) the files under 'www/' folder. What you should use is the [File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).

Comment: Sorry, I used File and File transfer. I could never seem to get access to the application root directory. Have you seen any examples of copying a file from the application directory to a folder? If so please post. I havent been able to find anything.